# How to create a list of objects based on existing list of objects and the list of indexes in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of objects `list` and a list of indexes `indexes` and I want to create a `new_list` containing objects of the original list at indexes defined this list of indexes.
I tried several ways but couldn't do that.
For example if there are only 2 indexes in `indexes` list why the following doesn't work?
`new_list = [list[indexes[0]] + list[indexes[1]]]`
Will be happy to know the general way resolving this issue, for any length of indexes list.

Comment: If you want to process the list elements separately use zip(list1,list2)

Comment: sacul's solution will work, but the problem with what you have is that you are adding objects of you list rather than lists. it's confusing because you are using a variable 'list', which is the name of the python function for creating lists. if your list object was called L, you could do list([L[indexes[0]]]) + list([L[indexes[1]]]) and it would work. But don't do that.  sacul's solution is *the* way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works:

```
my_list=['a','b','c','d']
my_indices=[1, 3]

new_list = [my_list[i] for i in my_indices if i < len(my_list)]
```

The above list comprehension will get all elements of `my_list` at the indices in `my_indices`. The `if` is there so that you don't get a `IndexError: list index out of range` error.

Your problem was that you were using the `+` operator, which concatenates your objects:

```
>>> [my_list[my_indices[0]] + my_list[my_indices[1]]]
['bd']
```